# How to change SharePoint users domain

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem, central-administration, user-accounts, trusted-domain

I migrated my SharePoint 2016 from one domain to other ABC to XYZ.
But the user which are showing in SharePoint site is still the older one, is their any way that I can change my users domain to new one XYZ with the help of script.

Move-spuser will take huge time and effort.

Answer (score 3):

you have to use the move-spuser command to move the users from one domain to other. what you can do,

- create a CSV files which contains all ids
- Now create powershell script which loop through all ids from csv and run the move-spuser.

here are two examples which may help you.

[Migrating bulk SharePoint Users](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Migrating-bulk-SharePoint-72863e36)

[Migrate SharePoint UserProfiles from one Domain to another](https://medium.com/@huptdawas/migrate-sharepoint-userprofiles-from-one-domain-to-another-4b2e45e3ccdb)

Answer (score 1):

Just like Waqas said, you will have to use Move-SPUser. Just to add - You can use

`$farm.MigrateGroup($.oldlogin, $.newlogin)` to migrate security AD groups.

Scirpts you can have a look at
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/12/migrate-sharepoint-users-from-one-domain-to-another.html